# Best practice factory angular.js 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm want to create service with $http with angular.js as is shown in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Eoq0zmv5NnOpHvyccaS?p=preview)

But when I try to do it in angular 1.2 I can not have more than one function into the **factory** as is done here

Works in angular 1.0.2

```
app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
   return {
     getFoo: function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('foo.json').success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(){
          deferred.reject();
       });
       return deferred.promise;
     },
     getBar: function(callback) {
       $http.get('foo.json').success(callback);
     },
     testHttpGetResult: function (){
       return $http.get('foo.json');
     }
   }
});
```

How should I do it in angular 1.2? must I use a different approach(not a factory)?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

It Works, because have only a function(getFoo)

```
app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
   return {
     getFoo: function() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get('foo.json').success(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(){
          deferred.reject();
       });
       return deferred.promise;
     }
});
```

Comment: You can definitely have more than one method in a service in angular 1.2. What error do you get when you try this in angular 1.2?

Comment: _" I can not have more than one function into the factory"_ - prove it with a plunker.

Comment: Just to let you know, the code to reproduce what you want to do should be pasted into the question. A plunk or a fiddle should be supplementary, but no one should have to rely on that site being up in order to answer your question or to help them with their problem.

Comment: @drew_w I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'MyFunction'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that if you look at the code you have defined "getFoo" as follows:

```
getFoo: function() {
    // ... code here ...
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

When you call this routine you use the following code:

```
// "foo" represents a PROMISE, not the actual json value!
$scope.foo = myService.getFoo();
```

The routine isn't returning the value you expect though - rather it is returning a promise which is why the scope doesn't have what you expect. You need to use a ".then" syntax to actually get the data result from your routine. For some reason it seems that older versions of angular might have been doing this for you (possibly)?

Anyways, the issue isn't whether or not you can define multiple routines (you can), but how you call those routines.

**Edit**

In case I didn't make it clear enough the calling method marked "the clean way" shouldn't (and doesn't work). You should use the following instead:

```
// The clean way - FIXED
myService.getFoo().then(function (data){
   $scope.foo = data;
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: You are right, I can do that when I have only getFoo in my factory, but it does not work for me when I have more than one function(getFoo and getBar in the example)

Comment: @Andres I believe the link in Joachim's post explains why the promise used to (but no longer) works this way.

Comment: do you know why I can do `return {getFoo: function() {...}}` but not `return {getFoo: function() {...} , {getBar: function() {...}}` ??

Comment: @Andres Why is there an open curly brace right before "getBar:"? If you aren't able to get this to work given the advice provided in this thread it might be that you need to edit your question or open a new question!

Answer (score 3):

As of Angular 1.2, [promise unwrapping is optional](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577), and it will be disabled entirely in future versions of Angular.

In other words, your clean version as of 1.2 requires an opt-in and won't work at all in the future.

Comment: So, should I use a different approach? I want it work using the best way. Can you give an example or another hint?

Comment: @Andres The ".then" syntax as posted in my answer works fine. This is the recommended approach for running routines that return a promise.

Comment: @Andres Yes, I agree with drew_w, [.then() is the standard (Angular and otherwise) way of getting the value of a resolved promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#description_the-promise-api).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I found this article that helped me a lot.
Hope this will help others. It fallows drew_w's Answers.

http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/angularjs-promise-or-dealing-with-asynchronous-requests-in-angularjs

and this one is even better:
show route only after all promises are resolved
http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Comment: Thanks, I used something like first link at the end.